# List<T> vs IEnumerable<T> in foreach

Tags: c#, linq, foreach

I was trying to get some Lists sorted using `OrderBy` within a foreach loop, but for some reason they weren't maintaining their sort order outside of the loop. Here's some simplified code and comments to highlight what was happening:

```
public class Parent
{
    // Other properties...
    public IList<Child> Children { get; set; }
}

public IEnumerable<Parent> DoStuff()
{
    var result = DoOtherStuff() // Returns IEnumerable<Parent>
        .OrderByDescending(SomePredicate) 
        .ThenBy(AnotherPredicate); // This sorting works as expected in the return value.

    foreach (Parent parent in result)
    {
        parent.Children = parent.Children.OrderBy(YetAnotherPredicate).ToList();
        // When I look at parent.Children here in the debugger, it's sorted properly.
    }

    return result;
    // When I look at the return value, the Children are not sorted.
}
```

*However*, when I instead assign `result` like this:

```
var result = DoOtherStuff()
    .OrderByDescending(SomePredicate)
    .ThenBy(AnotherPredicate)
    .ToList(); // <-- Added ToList here
```

then the return value has the Children sorted properly in each of the Parents.

What is the behavior of `List<T>` vs an `IEnumerable<T>` in a foreach loop?

There seems to be some sort of difference since turning result into a List fixed the problems with sorting in the foreach loop. It *feels* like the first code snippet creates an iterator that makes a copy of each element when you do the iteration with foreach (and thus my changes get applied to the copy but not the original object in `result`), while using `ToList()` made the enumerator give a pointer instead.

What's going on here?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The difference is that one is an expression that can procuce a set of `Parent` objects, and the other is a list of `Parent` objects.

Each time that you use the expression, it will use the original result from `DoOtherStuff` and then sort them. In your case it means that it will create a new set of `Parent` objects (as they obviously don't retain the children from the previous use).

This means that when you loop through the objects and sort the children, those objects will be thrown away. When you use the expression again to return the result, it will create a new set of objects where the children naturally is in the original order.

Comment: @user2864740: I see what you mean. I corrected the answer.

Comment: This is correct.... Easily checked by placing a break point in DoOtherStuff().  Each time the you iterate through the enumerator (IEnumerable<Parent>) DoOtherStuff will be called.  Call ToList() executes the enumerator and places the result in a list.  Iterating through the list will not hit the breakpoint in DoOtherStuff()

Comment: @Mick: The `DoOtherStuff` method won't actually be called again, but code inside the method may be executed again. The method returns an enumerator, and when it is recreated the code that created it will run again.

Comment: True... It might be possible to place the breakpoint within a lambda function used to create the enumeration, presuming that lamda function is executed against an in memory collection.  If it is Entity framework it would be interpreted rather than executed.  You'd be able to see the query executed each time in SQL Profiler.

Comment: @Guffa I'm a bit late to the party, but thanks for the response. I didn't accept it all those years ago because I had no idea what you were saying at the time, but now I'm older and wiser and understand better how `IEnumerable<T>`s and `System.Linq` work, and this answer is spot-on.

Answer (score 2):

Sample code of what likely happens to add to [Guffa's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32215825/477420):

```
class Parent { public List<string> Children; }
```

Enumerable of "Parent", will create new "Parent" objects *every time* it is iterated:

```
var result = Enumerable.Range(0, 10)
      .Select(_ => new Parent { Children = new List<sting>{"b", "a"});
```

Now first iteration with `foreach` there will be 10 "Parent" objects created (one for each iteration of the loop) and promptly discarded at the end of each iteration:

```
foreach (Parent parent in result)
{
    // sorts children of just created parent object
    parent.Children = parent.Children.OrderBy(YetAnotherPredicate).ToList();

    // parent is no longer referenced by anything - discarded and eligible for GC
}
```

When you look at `result` again it will be re-iterated and new set of "Parent" objects created *every time* you look at it, hence "Children" are not sorted.

Note that depending on how `DoOtherStuff() // Returns IEnumerable<Parent>` is implemented result could be different. I.e. `DoOtherStuff()` can return collection of existing items from some cached collection:

```
 List<Parent> allMyParents = ...; 

 IEnumerable<Parent> DoOtherStuff()
 {
      return allMyParents.Take(7);
 }
```

Now every iteration of `result` will give you new collection, but each item in the collection will just be an item from `allMyParents` list - so modification "Children" property would change the instances in `allMyParents` and change would stick.

Answer (score -1):

> **Remarks**
>
> The ToList(IEnumerable) method forces immediate
> query evaluation and returns a List that contains the query
> results. You can append this method to your query in order to obtain a
> cached copy of the query results.

From: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb342261(v=vs.110).aspx

If you omit the ToList() the query is not evaluated... Your debugger might do that for you but that is just a wild guess of me.