# To Order By Descending sub-elements using LINQ or Lambda Expression

Tags: c#, lambda, foreach

I had a problem to order sub-elements in List and found the topic to discuss  [List<T> vs IEnumerable<T> in foreach](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32215762/listt-vs-ienumerablet-in-foreach#) .I wonder how to order child List by using LINQ or Lambda Expression. Can someone recommend me? the code example as follows:

```
public class Parent
{
    // Other properties...
    public IList<Child> Children { get; set; }
}

public IEnumerable<Parent> DoStuff()
{
    var result = DoOtherStuff() // Returns IEnumerable<Parent>
        .OrderByDescending(SomePredicate) 
        .ThenBy(AnotherPredicate); // This sorting works as expected in the return value.

    foreach (Parent parent in result)
    {
        parent.Children = parent.Children.OrderBy(YetAnotherPredicate).ToList();
        // When I look at parent.Children here in the debugger, it's sorted properly.
    }

    return result;
    // When I look at the return value, the Children are not sorted.
}
```

Comment: You should either use ToList() after you order the DoOtherStuffResult(), or use yield return from the foreach in your sample.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You enumerate `result` each time that you enumerate the return `IEnumerable` of `DoStuff`, plus one additional time inside the loop in `DoStuff` itself. Modifications you make inside the loop do not stay, though, because of *deferred execution*: next time you enumerate `DoStuff()` there is another call to `DoOtherStuff` etc.

You can fix this in several ways:

- Convert `result` to list before sorting children, i.e.

  ```
  DoOtherStuff() // Returns IEnumerable<Parent>
  .OrderByDescending(SomePredicate) 
  .ThenBy(AnotherPredicate)
  .ToList();
  ```
- Add child sorting in a `Select`:

  ```
  DoOtherStuff() // Returns IEnumerable<Parent>
  .Select(parent => {
      parent.Children = parent.Children.OrderBy(YetAnotherPredicate).ToList();
      return parent;
  })
  .OrderByDescending(SomePredicate) 
  .ThenBy(AnotherPredicate)
  .ToList();
  ```
- Use `yield return result` in the loop (this is a variation of the `Select` solution).